# Hammersley–Clifford theorem

Tags: probability, deep-learning

I'm reading this paper http://image.diku.dk/igel/paper/AItRBM-proof.pdf and I got stuck in page 4 with equation (1) that's based on Hammersley–Clifford theorem. I'm not good in reading set theory notation and also I wasn't able to understand the point from the equation.

I couldn't understand what are $x_c$ and $\hat{x}_c$

Here's the section, I'm stuck just at equation (1):

[image]
[image]

Comment: That $\widehat{x}$ denotes a different random variable in the set. This says that if $x_c$ and $\widehat{x}_c$ are two observations in the same clique, the potential function evaluated at $x_c$ and $\widehat{x}_c$ is equivalent.